# Priority on group by in pandas data frame

Tags: pandas

I need to select letters from Col_2 into new_col. I want to give priority based on values like in Col_2 when there are 2 values: A, B. I need A to be given more selection priority over B in cases when there are 2 values as determined by col_1.

```
Col_1      Col_2        new_col
1            A             A
1            B             A
2            B             B 
3            A             A 
4            B             A
4            A             A
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ordered categoricals with set priority by ordering in column parameter `categories` and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return Series with same size like original filled by `max` values:

```
df['Col_2'] = pd.Categorical(df['Col_2'], ordered=True, categories=['B','A'])

#another solution for lower pandas versions
#df['Col_2'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['Col_2'], ordered=True, categories=['B','A'])

df['new_col1'] = df.groupby('Col_1')['Col_2'].transform('max')
print (df)
   Col_1 Col_2 new_col new_col1
0      1     A       A        A
1      1     B       A        A
2      2     B       B        B
3      3     A       A        A
4      4     B       A        A
5      4     A       A        A
```

Another solution with double [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary with priorities:

```
d = {'A':2, 'B':1}
#swap keys with values
d1 = {v:k for k, v in d.items()}
df['new_col1'] = df['Col_2'].map(d).groupby(df['Col_1']).transform('max').map(d1)
print (df)
   Col_1 Col_2 new_col new_col1
0      1     A       A        A
1      1     B       A        A
2      2     B       B        B
3      3     A       A        A
4      4     B       A        A
5      4     A       A        A
```